# Rendering texture in OpenGL shader

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt5

I am trying to learn how to apply a texture to OpenGL objects within the fragment shader but seem to just end up with static. Here is the python code I have so far for doing this with PyOpenGL.

```
class GLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        QtOpenGL.QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.yRotDeg = 0.0

    def initializeGL(self):
        self.initGeometry()

        self.vertex_code = """
            #version 120
            uniform float scale;
            attribute vec4 color;
            attribute vec2 texcoord;
            attribute vec2 position;
            varying vec4 v_color;
            varying vec2 v_texcoord;
            void main()
            {
                gl_Position = vec4(scale*position, 0.0, 1.0);
                v_color = color;
                v_texcoord = texcoord;
            } """

        self.fragment_code = """
            #version 120
            uniform sampler2D tex;
            varying vec4 v_color;
            varying vec2 v_texcoord;
            void main()
            {
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, v_texcoord);
            } """

        ## Build and activate program
        # Request program and shader slots from GPU
        self.program = GL.glCreateProgram()
        self.vertex = GL.glCreateShader(GL.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        self.fragment = GL.glCreateShader(GL.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

        # Set shaders source
        GL.glShaderSource(self.vertex, self.vertex_code)
        GL.glShaderSource(self.fragment, self.fragment_code)

        # Compile shaders
        GL.glCompileShader(self.vertex)
        GL.glCompileShader(self.fragment)

        # Attach shader objects to the program
        GL.glAttachShader(self.program, self.vertex)
        GL.glAttachShader(self.program, self.fragment)

        # Build program
        GL.glLinkProgram(self.program)

        # Get rid of shaders (not needed anymore)
        GL.glDetachShader(self.program, self.vertex)
        GL.glDetachShader(self.program, self.fragment)

        # Make program the default program
        GL.glUseProgram(self.program)

        # Create array object
        self.vao = GL.glGenVertexArrays(1)
        GL.glBindVertexArray(self.vao)

        # Request buffer slot from GPU
        self.data_buffer = GL.glGenBuffers(1)
        self.indices_buffer = GL.glGenBuffers(1)

        # Make this buffer the default one
        GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.data_buffer)

        # Upload data
        GL.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.data.nbytes, self.data, GL.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

        ## Bind attributes
        self.stride = self.data.strides[0]
        self.offset = ctypes.c_void_p(0)
        self.loc = GL.glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "position".encode('utf-8'))
        GL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.loc)
        GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.data_buffer)
        GL.glVertexAttribPointer(self.loc, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, False, self.stride, self.offset)

        self.offset = ctypes.c_void_p(self.data.dtype["position"].itemsize)
        self.loc = GL.glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "color".encode('utf-8'))
        if self.loc != -1:
            print('COLOR')
            GL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.loc)
            GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.data_buffer)
            GL.glVertexAttribPointer(self.loc, 4, GL.GL_FLOAT, False, self.stride, self.offset)

        self.offset = ctypes.c_void_p(self.data.dtype["texcoord"].itemsize)
        self.loc = GL.glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "texcoord".encode('utf-8'))
        if self.loc != -1:
            print('TEXCOORD')
            GL.glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.loc)
            GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.data_buffer)
            GL.glVertexAttribPointer(self.loc, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, False, self.stride, self.offset)

        ## BEGIN TEX

        img = Image.open('kitten.png') # .jpg, .bmp, etc. also work
        img_data = np.array(list(img.getdata()), np.int8)

        texture = GL.glGenTextures(1)
        GL.glPixelStorei(GL.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1)
        GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
        GL.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.GL_CLAMP)
        GL.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.GL_CLAMP)
        GL.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR)
        GL.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR)
        GL.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGB, img.size[0], img.size[1], 0, GL.GL_RGB, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)

        self.loc = GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.program, "tex".encode('utf-8'))
        print(self.loc)
        GL.glUniform1i(self.loc, 0)

        GL.glActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0 + 0)
        GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)

        ## END TEX

        self.offset = ctypes.c_void_p(self.indices.itemsize)
        GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.indices_buffer)
        GL.glBufferData(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sys.getsizeof(self.indices), self.indices, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        ## Bind uniforms
        self.loc = GL.glGetUniformLocation(self.program, "scale".encode('utf-8'))
        GL.glUniform1f(self.loc, 1.0)


    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        if height == 0: height = 1

        GL.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION)
        GL.glLoadIdentity()
        aspect = width / float(height)

        GLU.gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 1.0, 100.0)
        GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW)

    def paintGL(self):
        GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        #GL.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)

        self.offset = ctypes.c_void_p(self.indices.itemsize)
        GL.glDrawElements(GL.GL_QUADS, 4, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, self.offset)

    def initGeometry(self):
        # Indices not implemented yet (need to get correct size for it as well)
        self.data = np.zeros(4, [("position", np.float32, 2),
                            ("color",    np.float32, 4),
                            ("texcoord", np.float32, 2)])
        self.data['color']    = [ 
            (1,0,0,1),
            (0,1,0,1),
            (0,0,1,1),
            (1,1,0,1)
        ]
        self.data['position'] = [
            (-1,-1),
            (-1,+1),
            (+1,-1),
            (+1,+1)
        ]

        self.data['texcoord'] = [
            (1,1),
            (1,1),
            (1,1),
            (0,1)
        ]

        self.indices = np.array([
            0,
            2,
            3,
            1
        ], dtype=np.uint8)



    def spin(self):
        #print('spin')
        self.yRotDeg = (self.yRotDeg  + 1) % 360.0
        self.parent.statusBar().showMessage('rotation %f' % self.yRotDeg)
        self.updateGL()
```

I'm using Qt5 as the windowing framework but when I run the program, the vertices are displayed correctly, and the colors are displayed correctly, but the texture that should be overlayed on top just seems to be noise.

Here is a [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61w1p2ovrw8ckoy/opengl_app_output.mp4?dl=0) of what I'm ending up with. I can throw the full code on GitHub or something as well if this isn't enough, but it seems like this includes all the relevant info. What might I be doing wrong here?

EDIT:
Ok, I took Reto's advice and updated my code and that seems to have mostly fixed my problem except that my texture is now split in half and rendered upside down.. Here's the result:

[image: OpenGL results]

Any idea what I'm missing here. I thought I must have just put my coordinates in the wrong order but it seems that changing their order doesn't change the orientation at all.

Comment: I haven't looked at the whole code, but why aren't you using the texture coordinates you're passing into the shader? You're trying to use `gl_TexCoord[0]` instead, which is a legacy fixed function attribute. Actually, there seems to be some code missing to fully set up your texture coordinates. The code looks incomplete, you need to set up the texture coordinate attribute just like the position and color attributes.

Comment: Yeah, I originally set up the texture coordinates as well, but since I've had trouble getting this to work, I thought I could take one piece at a time. I realize this wont actually map the texture to the whole object, but shouldn't this map the texture to half the object (the 0 to 1 portion)?

Comment: I took your advice and put the texture coordinates back in and have been able to get the texture mostly working except that now it's cut in half and rendered upside down. I updated the code in my post. Would you mind having one more look? Changing the order of the texture coordinates doesn't change the result for some reason.

Comment: @hobenkr: Most likely your image data is using 4 bytes per pixel (one padding byte or alpha). So I suggest you specify GL_RGBA for the *format*; you don't have to use the alpha channel.

Comment: @datewolf I actually checked that using the PIL image library and it's RGB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I totally understand the python specifcs of this code, but: with the texcoords as they are currently in your code, you shouldn't get that image at all. 3 of the four are identical, you define some zero-area triange in texture space. You should see some completely single-colored triangle and one triangle weirdly colord from a single line in the image.

However, I think those texcoords are never used at all. The culprit is how you set the attribute pointer for the `texcoord` attribute:

```
self.offset = types.c_void_p(self.data.dtype["texcoord"].itemsize)
```

You probably mean something like

```
self.offset = types.c_void_p(self.data.dtype["position"].itemsize + self.data.dtype["color"].itemsize )
```

to skip the position and color data, which is also consistent with how you set up the "color" attribute by skipping position there.

Currently, you actually seem to point somewhere into your color data for your texcoord attribute, which happens to be some nice 0 and 1 sequences.